# Error al desplegar spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Soy nuevo en spring boot, cree un ejemplo basico sin conexion a BD, solo tengo la dependencia spring-boot-starter-web y spring-boot-starter

Mi clase main:

```
package com.sinbugs.contacts;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class EasyNotes1Application {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        return "Hola por fa";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EasyNotes1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

POM:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sinbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>contact-ws</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>easy-notes1</name>
    <description>Servicio web REST simple</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Cuando hago correr el aplicativo(Salid de la consola):

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.2.RELEASE)

2018-05-31 09:19:14.120  INFO 4052 --- [           main] c.s.contacts.EasyNotes1Application       : Starting EasyNotes1Application on tony with PID 4052 (C:\Users\antony\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE\easy-notes1\target\classes started by antony in C:\Users\antony\Documents\workspace-sts-3.9.1.RELEASE\easy-notes1)
2018-05-31 09:19:14.124  INFO 4052 --- [           main] c.s.contacts.EasyNotes1Application       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-05-31 09:19:14.199  INFO 4052 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d47c63f: startup date [Thu May 31 09:19:14 COT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-31 09:19:16.118  INFO 4052 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-05-31 09:19:16.146  INFO 4052 --- [           main] c.s.contacts.EasyNotes1Application       : Started EasyNotes1Application in 2.852 seconds (JVM running for 4.202)
2018-05-31 09:19:16.149  INFO 4052 --- [       Thread-3] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d47c63f: startup date [Thu May 31 09:19:14 COT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-05-31 09:19:16.151  INFO 4052 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
```

Pero ingreso a la Url: localhost:8080 y me rechaza la conexion.

Comment: Consejo, pon en texto lo que sale de la consola en vez de con imagen.

Comment: No estoy seguro que puedas poner un `@Controller` en la misma clase que inicializa la aplicación.

Comment: @VictorHerasmePerez me guie de la documentacion oficial

Comment: Pasa el link a la documentatión. Una posibilidad es que ya estés utilizando el puerto 8080. Puedes ir al archivo `application.properties` y añadir una linea como esta: `server.port=9999`

Comment: no levanta el servidor

Comment: Escribe todo el stack trace del error y pásanos el link a la documentación que has utilizado de ejemplo. La imágen que has puesto no sirve de mucho

Comment: documentacion:https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/     En consola no me sale ningun error , pero editare la pregunta

Comment: Ya pudiste resolverlo?

Comment: Publica tu POM. Para que maven corra el servidor embebido necesita una línea `<packaging>jar</packaging>` Por cierto. Te recomiendo empezar con los tutoriales de ejemplo. Son más fáciles de seguir. La guía de referencia presenta muchos puntos que aun no ocupas saber. Recomiendo empezar de manera general para que no te sientas frustrado con estos detalles.

Comment: Te recomiendo https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/ . Si te pierdes vienen los proyectos en GIT para que los revises. También te recomiendo que utilizes https://start.spring.io/ para crear el nuevo proyecto. Viene con todas las configuraciones para ponerte a trabajar en el código y no pasarte la vida configurando.

Comment: @Angel al parecer no levanta el tomcat ,añadire el POM

Comment: Te recomiendo que a tu controlador rest le coloques `@RequestMapping` para que lo mapee

Answer (score 2):

Deja unicamente estas dependencias:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

El starter web ya tiene un tomcat embebido. Como buena practica te recomiendo separar tu clase de configuracion de los controllers.

Saludos